# UTF-8 encoding wifstream getline for linux

Tags: c++, file, stream, ifstream

I am writing a code that will work on both linux and windows (and if that means introducing a few ifdef macros that is fine). The linux getline for wifstream seems to accept only wchar_t and since wchar_t is compiler specific implementation I dont get the desired result when I try to read the word `poké`.

Here is a snippet of my implementation:

```
std::wifstream GetFp()
{
    auto fp =  std::wifstream (path, std::wifstream::binary);
    const std::locale utf8_locale
                = std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<WCHAR>());
            fp.imbue(utf8_locale);
}
```

Later I get this make this a unique pointer as:

```
auto ifs = std::make_unique<std::wifstream>(GetFp());
```

Under the readfile function there is a for loop which get line by line from the file. A read line function which is called as `getline(ifs.get()` is implemented as follows:

```
bool getline(std::wistream* ifs)
{
#ifndef XPLATFORM
    TChar buf[8192];
#else
    wchar_t buf[8192];
#endif
ifs->getline(buf, _countof(buf));
if (ifs->eof())
   return false;
return true;
}
```

If I try any other datatype apart from wchar_t for the linux implementation it keeps giving me compilation issues. Any suggestions to fix this will be really helpful.

Comment: `wchar_t` doesn't have anything to do with UTF8 encoding. Read [Joel's article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) please (one rare about real value).

Comment: yes, I have. I just wanted to present a working snippet of the code. If I dont use wchar_t it gives me a compilation error.

Comment: If you use *wide strings/streams* and `wchar_t` you will be using `UTF-16` on Windows and `UTF-32` on Linux. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Trancey `whchar_t` and `TChar` are merly just typedefs for `short` instead of `char`. UTF-8 encoding more relies about 4 bytes, not 2. Read that article thoroughly once again.

Comment: Okay, I will go through that article again and see if I am missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use `std::getline` and always use `std::wstring` on Windows?

Comment: @Galik I am working on a large code base and I dont have much flexibility at that. However I must say your previous comment was indeed helpful to asking some pertinent questions about existing design. I almost think that will help in unblocking me. Thanks!