# Why does std::getline() seem to mess up accented characters?

Tags: c++, c++20, getline, wstring, wifstream

I am trying to use and display French accented characters in my C++20 program.

However, using `std::getline()` to read inside a file seems to mess up accented characters, like so:

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    std::wifstream  file("test.txt");
    std::wstring    s;
    std::getline(file, s);
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Content of test.txt **(encoded in UTF-8)**:

```
Salut ! Comment ça va ? éèêëâàäáôûöüùîï
```

Result:

```
$>./test
Salut ! Comment Ã§a va ? Ã©Ã¨ÃªÃ«Ã¢Ã Ã¤Ã¡Ã´Ã»Ã¶Ã¼Ã¹Ã®Ã¯
```

However, when I try to display the same text as a `const std::wstring`, the result has no problem:

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    std::wstring    s = L"Salut ! Comment ça va ? éèêëâàäáôûöüùîï";
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$>./test
Salut ! Comment ça va ? éèêëâàäáôûöüùîï
```

Using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` has made the problem better, as before even the second example would not work, but there seems to be a problem with `std::getline()` that I don't get.

I read that I might need to imbue a locale into the `std::wifstream`, but I could not understand how to make it work.

I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm not sure if there are better tools for this kind of problem, at least I couldn't find any.

I'm using zsh on MinGW, integrated into VSCode.

I compile with the following command:

```
c++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++20 test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: AFAIK, you need to `imbue()` the `wifstream` with a suitable `std::locale` to handle the file's UTF-8 encoding. `setlocale()` won't cut it.

Comment: Alternatively, forget about wide character streams. Use `std::ifstream`, `std::string`, and `std::cout`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Even if the narrow-character classes are used instead of the wide-character classes, you would still have to make sure you handle the UTF-8 properly.  Just because the file uses UTF-8 doesn't mean the console does, etc.

Comment: It is stated above that the contents of the file appear correctly in the terminal.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am using wide character strings because regular strings do not work with accented characters. Using what you mentioned breaks the second example in the same way the first one broke.  The first example stays just as broken.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Reading UTF-8 text and converting to UTF-16 using standard C++ wifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636374/), [How to read UTF-8 encoded text file using std::ifstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296237/), [UTF-8 encoding wifstream getline for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013162/)

Comment: Well-posed question. If it's a duplicate, may it live on and contribute as a landing page.

Comment: I wasn't sure from the question presented.  Is `test.txt` in UTF-8 encoding, or UTF-16 encoding, or some other encoding?

Comment: How is the file encoded?

Comment: @Eljay The txt file is encoded in UTF-8, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: "I'm using zsh on MinGW, integrated into VSCode." <--- your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem thanks to [this post](https://sockbandit.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/c-read-and-write-utf-8-file-using-standard-libarary/)!
Imbuing was the solution, here is what solved my problem:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    std::wifstream  file("test.txt");
    file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
    std::wstring    s;
    std::getline(file, s);
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This line:

```
file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
```

was originally:

```
file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
```

However, `std::locale::empty()` is platform-specific as seen in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753308/c11-is-stdlocaleempty-even-a-thing) so I replaced it by `std::locale()` and it worked fine.

Comment: `codecvt_utf8` [is deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8), just FYI.